# Is there some way to associate "sites" with "Articles"?

Tags: visualforce, knowledge, articles, public

I was describing a problem to someone, and to make a long story short, they sent me a list of suggested steps which included making a site (Develop > Sites) and adding a robots.txt so that site wouldn't be searched(done).

They then somehow implied that I could make an Article that is part of the Public Knowledge Base, and yet somehow make it unsearchable by associating it with this site. It seemed to make sense at the time, but now in retrospect, I literally have no idea what they're talking about. Is there some way to associate a Public Knowledge Base Article with a site and its robots.txt?

Answer (score 1):

On a site, you can specify what knowledge articles can be searched, either by Data Category, knowledge article type, etc etc...

Then you can specify in your robots.txt what sites you want indexed or not by external web spiders, robots, etc.. (as you have already done)

you can refer to some documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites) in regards to sites.

[here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=category_whatis.htm&type=0) for info on data categories, but you might want to read more on knowledge management [here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/206/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_knowledge_implementation_guide.pdf) .

Comment: >>> On a site, you can specify what knowledge articles can be searched, either by Data Category, knowledge article type, etc etc...

Thanks, but where can you specify that?

Comment: You can create an apex class to display what article(s) types to display in a page, use it as your page controller.